# How to scroll a richtextbox programmatically in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm creating an app for windows phone using a [richtextbox from ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/RichTextBoxPhone/).

Whenever I press a button the richtextbox text changes, what I want to achieve is  to scroll to the  the bottom of that richtextbox by pressing that button. And by pressing another button I want to scroll the top of that richtextbox.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to the bottom:

```
rtb.ScrollTo(rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
```

To scroll to the top:

```
rtb.ScrollTo(rtb.Document.ContentStart);
```